# Using Linq to query data based on dictionary object in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am writing linq query and finding it difficult to construct the logic using linq syntax. Basically I need to extract records that match the indexid and filter records based on values in the dictionary object period. The dictionary object contains key value pair containing year and months of the that year. For e.g 
year would be 2011 and months of the year would be 10,11,12

I need to extract records based on each years months. So my recordset should contain data for 10,11 and 12 months of 2011 and 2 and 3 months in 2012 etc.

```
    private List<Tuple<string, string, string, string>> GetFundStatistics(List<FundPerformanceVM> fundTrackRecord, int benchMark1, int benchMark2, Dictionary<int,int[]> period)
    {

     benchmark1Returns = GetViewService<MV_INDEX_PERFORMANCE>()
            .Where(x => x.Mtd != null && x.IndexId == benchMark1 && 'Need to add the condition here' )
            .Select(x => x.Mtd);

    }
```

The records would be for example

```
IndexID , PriceDate,       MTD
101.          12/01/2011     0.24
 101.         09/ 02/ 2011.    2.45
   102.       01/01/ 2012.    8.14
  101.        10/10/2009.     7.3
```

So here I could do PriceDate.Year and for month I could 
Do PriceDate.Month to query . But I need to compare the pricedate.year of the database value against the dictionary key value that contains the year similarly I need to compare pricedate.Month against the dictionary month array value

Comment: hi @tom can you provide more explicit example

Comment: Does `x` have a Date property?

Comment: Yes updated the post

Comment: There is a field called PriceDate. So I can do PriceDate.Year and PriceDate.Month

Comment: Just do `Where(x => period.Any(y => x.YourDbColumn == y.UseTheKeyOrValue)...`

Comment: I tried the above like     benchmark1Returns = GetViewService<MV_INDEX_PERFORMANCE>()
                .Where(x => x.Mtd != null && x.IndexId == benchMark1 && period.Any(y => x.PriceDate.Year == y.Key)).Select(x => x.Mtd);

Comment: and get the following error   System.NotSupportedException: 'Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Int32[], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.'

Comment: Is this a Linq to Object or Linq to SQL? There are some constructs in Linq to Object that cannot be translated in Linq to SQL

Comment: I am quite new to linq. Could you please guide me

Answer (score 0):

First flatten the `period` dictionary into a List of (year, month).

```cs
var periodTuples = period.ToList() // gives you List<KeyValuePair<int, int[]>>
                         .SelectMany(kvp => 
                             kvp.Value.Select(it2 => Tuple.Create(kvp.Key, it2)))
                         .ToHashSet(); // to optimize .Contains()
```

Then the condition inside is just `.Contains()` of that (year, month) tuple.

```
.Where(x => x.Mtd != null && x.IndexId == benchMark1 && 
            periodTuples.Contains(Tuple.Create(ptd.Year, ptd.Month)))
```

Comment: I am getting error System.NotSupportedException: 'Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Tuple`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.'

Comment: I think Tuple.Create can't be translated into SQL

Comment: Then please include in your question that you are asking in the context of Linq-to-SQL. As I mentioned, there are some constructs in Linq-to-Object that cannot be translated in Linq-to-SQL.

Comment: As an aside, if the query is too complex (like in this case), usually we will have no choice but to handcraft the query string ourselves. If you don't mind using yet another library, you can take a look at `Dapper.NET` just to pull the query result out nicely into objects, but have the query written using raw query string instead of expression tree. 
For the `List<KeyValuePair<int, int[]>>`, you can probably inject that parameter using a Table-Valued parameter.